# Ruby - Resource can't be re-used

Tags: ruby, azure

After the `network_sg.create` I can't use the `network_sg` for other purpose unless I create a new
`network_sg` resource.

Is there a way to get past this? I tried freeze `network_sg` but I get a Frozen Error while creating a new SG.

```
network_sg = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)

options = {
  :location => 'eastus',
}

network_sg.create('test-network_sg-4', rg, options)    
  
# Can't re-use the `network_sg` anymore. 
# And I have to recreate `network_sg = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)` before I can use it again.

network_sg.list_all.each do |network_sg|
    $evm.log('info', "azure network_sg test is: #{network_sg.name} ")  
end
```

Comment: Why did you tag the question as rails-related? This issue is very SDK-specific and it is nearly impossible to help you without even seeing the error message along with the stack trace... Take look at [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There are no error message. The code `network_sg.list_all` doesn't execute at all unless I redefine `network_sg = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)` .

Comment: If some external library's code doesn't work as expected you generally have 2 options: read the documentation or (rather "and") debug: `bundle open <the gem that doesn't work as expected>`, add a breakpoint to the `list_all`, trace the execution flow from the breakpoint until you find an exact place where thing get messed up and so forth

Comment: It seems setting the `network-sg` as CONSTANT worked. It can be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the network_sg as constant worked. It can be re-used.

`NETWORK_SG = Azure::Armrest::Network::NetworkSecurityGroupService.new(conf)`